# velocity parametric surface

Tags: analysis, surfaces, parametric

I have a parametric surface $S:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $S(x,z,t) = (x,h(x,z,t),z)$. This surface defined the surface of the water, the second component is the vertical axis and it represents the height of the surface of water at position $x$ and $z$ at time $t$.

I need to find the velocity vector at a given position of this surface. I tried to use partial derivative on $t$, but then the velocity vector will only have a value on $y$ component, which don't seem intuitive to me.

I think my problem is that I could not defined correctly what is the velocity of a parametric surface of this type... I don't even know if it exists with this type of object !

If someone have a definition of the velocity that I can rely on, I would appreciate it !

[image: Illustration of what I expect (I hope it's clear)]

Comment: Why do you expect the velocity vector should have non$-$zero components in the $x$ and $z$ directions?

If you take $h(x,z,t)=\sqrt{x^2+z^2}+t$ then $S(x,z,t):t\geq 0$ models the motion of the cone $y=\sqrt{x^2+z^2}$ whose vertex moves along on the positive $y-$axis at a rate of $1$ unit per second (assuming $t$ is in seconds).

Comment: I expect non zero component on $x$, $z$ directions, because my physical intuition of the velocity on the surface of the ocean is that the velocity on the surface will go toward the direction of the waves and not just in vertical direction ($S$ is only a convenient way to only represent this surface of the ocean by a height field).

Comment: You should be more explicit about which axis is which and what $h$ is. The velocity of the wavefront is not the same as the velocity of a particle of water on the wave. The wavefront moves as you expect but the water moves up and down in the usual case.

Comment: Sorry, I add informations about the axis and $S$ to I hope to be more clear. When you say "the water moves up and down in the usual case" are you talking about particle of water ?

Comment: Yes. In a simplified model, the wave propagates but the water particles move up and down. Your model may be more realistic in that there could be a drift as well as a vertical oscillation.

Comment: Have you an idea how I can compute this "drift" ? Can I deduce it from the velocity wavefront ?